# JavaScript not running on WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I wanna overwrite my WordPress page with some JavaScript code.
The JavaScript file is located in the js folder of the theme twenty sixteen itself and is showing up in the header. The interesting fact is that this works:

```
var z = document.getElementsByClassName("site-description").innerHTML = "TEXT"; 

window.alert(z);
```

The alert is running, but the webpage text itself is not changing.

SO this order is not working:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("site-description").innerHTML = "TEXT";
```

I found out that the JavaScript itself that I implemented in function.php through:

```
(add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mr_java_code_einfügen');
function mr_java_code_einfügen(){wp_enqueue_script('zusätzlicherjavacode',    
get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/scriptvonmartin.js');}        
function mr_java_code_einfügen(){wp_enqueue_script('zusätzlicherjavacode', 
get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/scriptvonmartin.js');}
```

is running before the header.php Code.

So theoretically the header.php just overrides the JavaScript again right? How can I let the script run as the latest/at the end of the body or as last of the whole HTML script?

I have the feeling that could solve the problem but not completely sure.....

Comment: Java is not JavaScript!

Comment: Sry spelling mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add JavaScript file to footer, not to header, you need to add corresponding argument to wp_enqueue_script() function.

Here is its usage:

```
 wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', 
array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false );
```

So, by default it is added to header.
To make it to be added to footer use this format:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mr_java_code_einfügen');

function mr_java_code_einfügen(){
wp_enqueue_script('zusätzlicherjavacode',    
get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/scriptvonmartin.js',array(),false,true);}
```

If even this doesn't help you, it means that the problem is not about script area, it about wrong classname.